# What are the ports used by the master to communicate with the worker nodes

Tags: azure-aks

The master node for AKS cluster is a public endpoint.How does the master node communicate with the worker nodes? What are the ports that are required for communication?

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Kubernetes, the master is managed by Azure and you do not need and also cannot manage it yourself unless you use the aks-engine. What you can manage are the nodes. The nodes communicate with the master using the API through port 443 like this:

[image]

As you see, you can get the list through the command `kubectl cluster-info` and get more details through the command `kubectl cluster-info dump` and it will be a lot of messages. I suggest you do not need to care about it because you cannot manage it. If you really want, just try the [aks-engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine).

Comment: Thank you..we are a bit concerned on how to pods communicate with the API endpoint, as this is a public. I have been told my Microsoft that it uses port 22 for kubelets to communicate with API..and 9000 as well (not sure what is this for though)!!